# Set up updating source code on server by Using GitHub’s Service Hooks

Tags: git, ssh, githooks

I followed [this article](http://www.thisprogrammingthing.com/2013/automatically-updating-your-website-using-githubs-service-hooks/)

I tried using this command `ssh -T git@github.com` and I received the feedback: `Hi Tran! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.` which shows that it's OK with my ssh key and GitHub account.

This's my repository's Webhook image:

[image]

I think the problem is the github.php file with the content:

```
<?php `git pull`;?>
```

I tried with replace ` with ' (single quote) but it's the same. After I push, I didn't see any change on my server.

Comment: Even, I tried to use shell_exec('git pull') in php file. But I didn't see any changes.

Answer (score -1):

This is a very bad idea... anyone could access your php file and update your code. But if you still want to do it that way, you need to upload a pair of ssh keys into your server (make sure they're in the right place) and also add the public key to your github account, maybe as a deployment key in your repo.

Comment: - Thanks for your idea! But please help me by comment your idea more details.

-About anyone could access my php file: this is very simple, just add a param as password. eg. http://mydomain.com/gitpull.php?p=a_pass_phase. I don't think anyone can guess my link and pass phase. ^^